ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'arichuvadi.valam'; 'arichuvadi' is not a package

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'arichuvadi.valam'; 'arichuvadi' is not a package
Installed the local package in editable form with the following command
#+begin_src shell
pip install -e .

#+end_src


I get this error when running the code like this
#+begin_src shell

    $ python mlm/arichuvadi/uyirmei.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/vanangamudi/code/arichuvadi/mlm/arichuvadi/uyirmei.py", line 1, in <module>
        from arichuvadi.valam import UYIRMEI_MAP_PATH
      File "/home/vanangamudi/code/arichuvadi/mlm/arichuvadi/arichuvadi.py", line 7, in <module>
        from arichuvadi.valam import (
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'arichuvadi.valam'; 'arichuvadi' is not a package

#+end_src

Here is the file layout
#+begin_src shell :results code

      tree

#+end_src

#+RESULTS:

#+begin_src shell

    .
    ├── LICENSE
    ├── MANIFEST.in
    ├── mlm
    │   ├── arichuvadi
    │   │   ├── arichuvadi.py
    │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │   │   ├── uyirmei.py
    │   │   └── valam.py
    │   ├── arichuvadi.egg-info
    │   │   ├── dependency_links.txt
    │   │   ├── PKG-INFO
    │   │   ├── SOURCES.txt
    │   │   └── top_level.txt
    │   ├── orunguri-tha.py
    │   └── tharavu
    │       ├── adaiyalamitta-ari.txt
    │       ├── ari.txt
    │       ├── ari-uni.txt
    │       └── uyir-mei.csv
    ├── pyproject.toml
    ├── README.txt -> YENNAI_PADI.txt
    ├── setup.py
    ├── YENNAI_PADI.txt
    └── YENNA_SEIYA.org
    
    4 directories, 20 files

#+end_src

It works when importing in repl
#+begin_src shell
 

     $ python
      Python 3.10.12 (main, Nov 20 2023, 15:14:05) [GCC 11.4.0] on linux
      Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
      >>> import arichuvadi
      >>> import arichuvadi.valam
      >>>

#+end_src

Please help!

It appears uyirmei.py and valam.py are within the same directory, so no need to specify a package name.
in uyirmei.py, try just import valam (not import arichuvadi.valam)

Not sure how you have your python files set up but make sure to also put a __init__.py in the arichuvadi folder. Try the run your script or module as part of a package. Based on your import through the REPL it looks likes you are treating your scripts like packages.
if your python files are set like this...
def main():

    ''' some code '''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

then you should try executing your scripts like python3 -m mlm.arichuvadi.uyirmei
or python3 -m arichuvadi.uyirmei depending what directory you are in and how you are importing different packages.
